# Solr Searching is not responding

Tags: java, solr

I am working in Solr 4.6.0 from last 2 months. I have indexed the data in solr. Indexing size is 8.3GB which is increasing day by day. While I'm searching in this index using java programming with multiple instances( more than 15 instance), the solr is not responding to the search query. Its getting too slow. Its taking more than 8 hours to search the 7lac data. I am Using Ubuntu machine with 24GB ram and 1TB HD. Kindly tell me the solution to solve this issue.

Comment: what did you already tried to find the problem?

Comment: Are you getting the same issue when you query from Admin window? The 15 instances you are talking about. Are these of 15 parallel call to your Solr or 15 Solr instance in your SolrCloud?